# Open Clipboard Intent and paste data into it using flutter

Tags: flutter

> When a user tap on button then clipboard intent should open and data paste to it automatically and only use this.

```
onPressed: (){
Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: quote));
 },
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use Flutter's existing library code to get the data from Clipboard using [getData method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/Clipboard/getData.html).

```
ClipboardData data = await Clipboard.getData('text/plain');
```

Comment: How can i open clipboard intent Programatically?

Comment: Opening clipboard intent programatically is quite difficult here, cos nothing is been mentioned till now. You have to manage your task using `getData` and `setData` only @TanzeemIqbal